# Weird behavior of 'soundcard' oscilloscope

Tags: sound-card

This is what I did

[image: I read somewhere that the soundcard can handle about 3 volts , so I figured 2.5 V wouldn't hurt]

I expected a nice square wave on my soundcard oscilloscope software but I'm getting this

[image]

What is happening ?

Comment: Well written question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

AC Coupling.

Sound cards have a capacitor in series with the input which acts as a high pass filter, removing frequencies lower than around 20Hz.

You appear to be feeding in a signal of only 2Hz which is basically going to get filtered into nothing more than an impulse response at each transition as you are seeing. The reason you see the impulse is that a step change in the signal voltage has a large bandwidth requirement - having many higher order harmonics which will not be filtered out.

Comment: Ah ! I see , Thanks , it works perfectly now that I have increased the frequency .

Comment: Wait , but why is it detecting a negative signal ?

Comment: @AnirudhGanesh AC Coupling. You signal that goes from 0-5V is essentially a +/-2.5V signal with a 2.5V DC offset. What frequency is DC? :)

Comment: .... 0 ? wouldn't that mean the DC part will be filtered out completely and nothing else would happen ??

Comment: @AnirudhGanesh correct, the DC part goes away. So you are left with just the +/-2.5V square wave, hence you see negative.

Comment: So , the +2.5 goes away and when it's flat , only the -2.5 is left and then the -2.5 gets filtered away ?  something like that ?

Comment: Not quite - the capacitor-resistor combo means that *changes* that are fast enough get passed through, but levels decay rapidly to 0V *on the soundcard side of the capacitor*. So the rising edge of the square wave turns into an upward spike. Then it decays. Then the falling edge turns into a downward spike.

Comment: @TomCarpenter You forget the voltage divider. He's only getting a +/- 1.25 volt signal to the sound card. That's probably why he thinks that 2.5 volts is "cut off" or something.

Comment: Ignore the DC, what's left of his square wave? There's a quick "pop" positive, then nothing for awhile, then a quick "pop" negative, then nothing for awhile, and then it repeats. So that's what you see.

Comment: And *this* is why using a sound card as an oscilloscope is crazy.  Seriously -- you can buy a USB scope on ebay for < $30 these days, and they can handle both DC and substantially higher frequencies than a sound card can.